# How to access to upload folder in Yii framework?

Tags: php, yii, upload

how to access to the upload folder in Yii framework?

I upload images and electronic books files to the upload folder and when i try to access to this folder it gives me a message

> you don't have permission to access this page .....

I use an extension YCM  for content management  and this extension upload the files to this folder ...can any body help me please

the code is

```
<?php echo CHtml::image('uploads/gallery/java.jpg', 'DORE'); ?>
```

the message for pdf files is

> You don't have permission to access /izen/uploads/file/file_url/c00e36dbd6f6d520ac4d6c8f04d0d6d9.pdf on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: could you run fileperms("/izen/uploads/file/file_url/c00e36dbd6f6d520ac4d6c8f04d0d6d9.pdf") and tell us the result?

Comment: it's not work by fileperms() and give me error 
PHP warning

fileperms() [<a href='function.fileperms'>function.fileperms</a>]: stat failed for /izenoumar.pdf

Comment: you have to put the whole path to an existing file. You can't stat a file that doesn't exist

Comment: @darkheir right but this function from yii framework and its work in another application but me not work i don't now what the reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uploads folder is open not protected but the problem in two thing 
1- the url to file is wrong 
2- the folder is protected and this problem from the server linux and os becuse the permmision  for the folder is not allow to access to this folder ....will be change the prmission of the folder